# How to import .pm by Process Maker 4.0

Tags: processmaker

I have a process maker 3.0 of format "pm". Any assistance in
How to import .pm file by Process Maker 4.0
Bests

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a place where people will write your code for you - if you have requirements and need them turned into a working end product, hire a developer. If you have an attempt, please edit your question to include your code as a Minimal, Reproducible Example, along with a succinct explanation of what you expect said code to do, and why it doesn't meet that expectation or your requirements. See How to Ask and On topic.

Answer (score 0):

ProcessMaker, the company, has built a tool that will do the automatic conversion of ProcessMaker 3 pm files to the ProcessMaker 4 format.  You should reach out to ProcessMaker if you are interested in testing the tool and/or using it.

Otherwise, you can always just rebuild it manually in PM4.

Comment: I reached them and they said they do not have. I can not open to redesign. I appreciate your care.

Answer (score 0):

I think ProcessMaker 4 is a completely new platform and it can not be associated with its previous versions. You will have to recreate the entire process in ProcessMaker 4.

Comment: Appreciate your comments